# Read the notification of AT+CPBR and store it

Tags: arduino, at-command

Here is my problem. I sent these two commands:

```
sendATcommand("AT+CPBS=\"SM\"", 500);   // Select the SIM phonebook

sendATcommand("AT+CPBR=1,99", 100);       // To read ALL phonebook
```

And I want to store the result of `AT+CPBR` in a variable. How can I do that?

Example of result: `+CPBR:1,"690506990",129,"ANDROID"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to read result/response from GSM Module just after issuing AT command.

```
char response[300];
for(int i = 0 ; Serial.available() > 0 && i<300 ; i++) {
   response[i] = Serial.read();
   if(response[i]=='\n'|response[i]=='\0'|response[i]=='\r'){
        response[i]=='\0'
        break;
   }
}
```

The response after AT command will be stored in `response[200]` character array.

Comment: THX for your answer but I don't receive good response.here is what I get:            `Sending AT COMMAND:
AT+CPBS="SM"
Received AT COMMAND:

OK  //the first at command don't have problem

Sending AT COMMAND:
AT+CPBR=1,99
Received AT COMMAND:

+CPBR: 1,"696444834",129,"ANDROID"  //the answer for the gsm module

OK

****************
ANSWER
´,         //my response variable who is a unread character
`

Comment: Why `i` is incremented twice ?

Comment: @isaac47 can you elaborate the problem? I can understand what you are telling

Comment: @Ouss4 when I sent this command `sendATcommand("AT+CPBR=1,99", 100);       // To read ALL phonebook` the serial monitor reply this `+CPBR:1,"690506990",129,"ANDROID" `.my problem is to put this reply in a variable,because I need that number for another part of my code.

Comment: @isaac47 You can try the function Salman gave you. The function stores the whole answer in a variable. You can then parse the variable to get your number using strings manipulation functions.

Comment: I have found a correct answer: `String result;  unsigned long startTime = millis();  while (millis() - startTime < milliseconds) {
                                if (fonaSS.available()) {
                                  char c = fonaSS.read();
                                  Serial.write(c);
                                  result += c;  // append to the result string
                                }
                              }
                             
                              Serial.println();  // new line after timeout.
                              return result;`